# Is it possible to show Toast(message) on a button with setEnabled(false)

Tags: android, button, android-toast

I would like that because I have a button which has `setEnabled(false)`( until user logs in) and I want it to show me message `"You have to login to create receipt"`. Also i have login button in ActionBar which changes when the user logs in, to "Logged in as `UserName` ".

Is that possible or should I just enable it back and then make that message if user has not logged in.

Comment: Can you post what you have done? code, xml?

Comment: A Toast is a **quickly vanishing** window. The user could even be distracted and **miss it**. I'd prefer a **Dialog** (the user has to close it). OR, as an alternative, a **TextView** that stays visible until the user is logged in.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Good point, but in my action bar I have Login, that is why I just need a message to let the user know why the button is disabled. But I might do it with Dialog.

Comment: I think is better to take user to Login screen if not Login instead of Toast.

Comment: You could also set the title of your ActionBar. I didn't know you were using an ActionBar (it's not a must). "Not logged" or something similar, very short. Once logged, re set the title to `@string/app_name`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Yeah just edited my question with that. But some users like to click on buttons and they get confused because they are "not working" (in this case because its not enabled), that is why I taught of doing it this way.

Comment: What I would do is to have at first only a Login Button visible enabled, so the user is forced to click it. Then hide it and unhide a TextView saying "Logged as ..."

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I did it that way.Guess I will have to leave it this way or make it as blackbelt suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could leave it enabled and checked for the login status in the `Button`'s `onClickListener`. Something like:

```
if (!loggedIn) {
  // show toast
  return;
} 

// other logic here
```

Comment: I taught it was possible somehow. Yeah I guess I will have to make it this way.